# Define xmlns in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin Forms application. I created another PCL library for keeping UI constants like Color codes.

Portable project name is App. 
PCL library project is Utilities.
 Defined this in my PCL lib

```
namespace App.Utilities
{
    public class Colors
    {
        public static Color ColorCode1 = Color.Aqua;
    }
}
```

Tried to define xmlns in xcml file like this.

```
xmlns:colors="clr-namespace:App.Utilities.Colors;assembly=App.Utilities"
```

But it is throwing xaml parse exception saying the above namespace cannot be found.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLNS declaration syntax is correct. Namespace need not include the class name. So In this case Namespace has to be just `App.Utilities` and not `App.Utilities.Colors`. Changing it to

```
xmlns:colors="clr-namespace:App.Utilities;assembly=App.Utilities"
```

will work provided your assembly name is correct.

You can verify if your assembly name is correct by Right-Clicking on PCL Forms prject > Options > Output (Under Build). There we can see the correct assembly name.

[image]

Comment: You just saved me. But I have one other problem. I see HelloWorld.iOS and HelloWorld.Droid in iOS and Android platforms respectively. Is there a way to define this platform universally?

Comment: Your requirement doesn't seem clear to me.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You have mentioned to look into the assemble name by Right-Clicking on the project. My app is a cross platform app which has both iOS and Android projects in a same solution. The assemble name for the iOS project  is HelloWord.iOS and the same for the Android project is HelloWord.Droid.

Comment: For now, I have added xmlns:colors="clr-namespace:HelloWorld;assembly=HelloWorld.iOS" which works in iOS but doesn't work in android, obviously. To make that work in Android, I have to change the assemble name to HelloWorld.Droid. Can you get my problem now?

Comment: Are you using a PCL for code-sharing or Shared Asset Projects ? Because in the scenario mentioned in the question, a PCL was used and the Utitlity Class Colors (which needed to be referenced in the XAML) was defined in the PCL. So basically the Assembly name of the PCL project was used instead of Android or iOS project.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it, I am using Shared Projects.