# Custom Entry xmlns:local error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm not able to include a Custom Entry in the `axml` file of my page. I'm copying and pasting the code of this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/).

**Custom Controll:**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyEntry : Entry
    {
        public MyEntry()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.Teste">
  <Label Text="teste" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

  <local:MyEntry x:Name="Entry" Text="In Shared Code" />
</ContentPage>
```

**App.cs:**

```
 MainPage = new Teste();
```

I'm getting this error:

> 56:43.847 E/mono    ( 3346): Unhandled Exception: 05-06 17:56:43.847
>   E/mono    ( 3346): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'MyApp' or one of its dependencies 05-06 17:56:43.847
>   E/mono    ( 3346): File name: 'MyApp' 05-06 17:56:43.847 E/mono    (
>   3346):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:99831900-fb04-4a45-85f3-99b1198ac963
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) 05-06 17:56:43.847 E/mono    ( 3346):   at
>   (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   System.Object:99831900-fb04-4a45-85f3-99b1198ac963
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) 05-06 17:56:43.847 E/mono-rt ( 3346): [ERROR]
>   FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'MyApp' or one of its dependencies 05-06
>   17:56:43.847 E/mono-rt ( 3346): File name: 'MyApp' 05-06 17:56:43.847
>   E/mono-rt ( 3346):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:99831900-fb04-4a45-85f3-99b1198ac963
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) 05-06 17:56:43.847 E/mono-rt ( 3346):   at
>   (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   System.Object:99831900-fb04-4a45-85f3-99b1198ac963
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) referenceTable GDEF length=670 1

Comment: are you sure the assembly is named "MyApp"?  Is it in a PCL or Shared Project?

Comment: Jason is in the Portable project

Comment: I strongly feel you might have a wromg assembly name in the xmlns string.  Check this answer on how to verify the correct assembly name http://stackoverflow.com/a/36836320/3319076