# Failed to resolve assembly for adding custom view in xaml using local tag in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application using Xamarin.Forms. Now, I am creating the custom view. But when I render the view in the xaml including namespace, it is giving me "Failed to resolve assembly" error. I looked up on these solutions - [Define xmlns in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836176/define-xmlns-in-xamarin-forms/36836320#36836320) and [Custom Entry xmlns:local error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081374/custom-entry-xmlnslocal-error). But it is still not working.

This is the CameraPage.xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp;assembly=MementoApp"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Padding="0,20,0,0"
             x:Class="MementoApp.Views.CameraPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Label Text="Camera Preview:" />
        <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

It is in the MementoApp.Views namespace.

I created the CameraPreview.cs in the MementoApp.Views namespace as well. This is the code.

```
namespace MementoApp.Views
{
    public enum CameraOptions
    {
        Rear,
        Front
    }

    public class CameraPreview : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Camera",
            returnType: typeof(CameraOptions),
            declaringType: typeof(CameraPreview),
            defaultValue: CameraOptions.Rear);

        public CameraOptions Camera
        {
            get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue(CameraProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CameraProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see for the namespace and assembly in xaml, I used

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp;assembly=MementoApp"
```

I tried using this as well.

```
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views;assembly=MementoApp.Views"
```

And this.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views;assembly=MementoApp"
```

All are not working. This is my project structure.

[image]

I tried using

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views;assembly=Memento"
```

as well. It is not working either.

Why it is not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views;assembly=Memento"`

Comment: No it is not working. MementoApp is the shared project.

Comment: A shared project does not produce an assembly. Check the project where the shared project is compiled in and what the name of that DLL file is

Comment: How can I check it, please?

Comment: A bit of effort on your part would be appreciated. It's not that hard. Right click your project and go to the properties, it should be somewhere in there. Or just check on the filesystem what name the dll file has.

Comment: By the way, if it is in the same assembly, which it probably is, you can just leave out the assembly part. So just try `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views"`

Comment: I believe it is Memento. There is a C# library project at the top. When I use "Memento" for the assembly, it is still not working. I tried excluding the assembly as your last comment. It is still not working as well.

Comment: The same error occurs when you set just one element as a child of the `ContentPage.Content` as it's expected (wrapping it all in a `StackLayout`, for example)?

Comment: Oh yeah. I got it working. All I needed to do is remove the assembly=Memento and wrap the view in the StackLayout. Thanks so much you all...........